# HTTP status 500 internal server error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Estou com um problema em minha aplicação web em spring boot compila e inicia o server, porém quando se inicia `localhost:8080/buscar` aparece o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Classe controller:

```
package com.web.app.Bresource;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.web.app.Cservice.Service;
import com.web.app.Emodel.Bicicleta;

/* Controlador*/
@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private Service Service;

        @RequestMapping("/buscar") //buscar todos
        public List<Bicicleta> getTodos() {
            return Service.getTodos();
        }

        @RequestMapping("/buscar/{id}")
        public Bicicleta getCodigo(@PathVariable int id) {
            return Service.getCodigo(id); //buscar por codigo
        }

        //metodo post
        @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/inserir")
        public void addDados(@RequestBody Bicicleta inserir) {
            Service.addDados(inserir);
        }

        //metodo put
        @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value="/atualizar/{id}")
        public void atualizarDados(@RequestBody Bicicleta atualizar, @PathVariable String id) {
            Service.atualizarDados(id, atualizar);
        }

        //metodo delete
        @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.DELETE, value="/delete/{id}")
        public Bicicleta deleteDados(@PathVariable String id) {
            return Service.deleteDados(id);
        }

        //colocando dados
        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String dados() {
            List<Bicicleta> bicicleta = new ArrayList<Bicicleta>();
            Bicicleta nova = new Bicicleta(0, "Kaloi", "doze", "monarca", 2, "kaloi");
            bicicleta.add(nova);

            return "Dados no sistema";
        }

}
```

Classe service:

```
package com.web.app.Cservice;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import com.web.app.Drepository.TopicRepository;
import com.web.app.Emodel.Bicicleta;
import com.web.app.Bresource.Controller;

@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    private TopicRepository repository; 

    //buscar todos
    public static List<Bicicleta> getTodos(){
        return getTodos();
    }

    //buscar por codigo
    public Bicicleta getCodigo(int id) {
        return getCodigo(id);
    }

    //adicionar
    public void addDados(Bicicleta inserir) {
        ((List<Bicicleta>) inserir).add(inserir);
    }

    public void atualizarDados(String marca, Bicicleta atualizar) {
        Bicicleta t = new Bicicleta();
        if(t.getMarca().equals(marca)) {
            atualizar.setMarca(marca);;
            return;
        }
    }

    //metodo para criar o delete
    public Bicicleta deleteDados(String id) {
        if(id.equals(id)) {
            deleteDados(id);
        }

        return deleteDados(id);
    }

}
```

Alguém já passou por isso poderia me ajudar?

Comment: O erro é bem claro, já que é um `StackOverflowError`. Basicamente seus métodos em `Service` estão chamando eles próprios recursivamente sem critério de parada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recomendo verificar também quando subir o servidor, verificar se o método "/buscar" está sendo registrado como GET, pois na sua declaração inicial apenas foi colocado o @RequestMapping (faltnado o atributo method)

No Spring 4.3 já é possível utilizar direto a anotação @GetMapping (bem como os outros demais verbos http)

Answer (score 1):

Cara, tem algumas coisas estranha no seu código. Vamos lá:

1. No método `getTodos()` da classe `Controller`, você está chamando o objeto `Service` com o mesmo nome da classe. Isso além de ser errado, pode gerar confusão. Mude para:

   ```
   @Autowired
   private Service service;
   ```
2. Na classe `Service`, você realiza o `@Autowired` em um objeto da classe `TopicRepository`, porém não o utiliza em nenhum método. Acredito que o método `getTodos()` esteja retornando uma sua própria instância aos invés da lista de todas as bicicletas. Acho que seria algo do tipo `return repository.findAll()`

Recomendo a você utilizar uma nomenclatura diferente ao invés dos nomes das annotations:

`public class Controller` => `public class BicicletaController`

`public class Service` => `public class BicicletaService`

Answer (score 1):

Fiz algumas modificações e tive êxito, coloquei assim:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/buscar", method = RequestMethod.GET) //buscar todos
public String list(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("Bicicletas", Service.getTodos());
    return "Bicicletas";
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class ServiceImplements implements com.web.app.Cservice.Service {

    @Autowired
    private TopicRepository topicrepository;

    public Iterable<Bicicleta> getTodos() {
        return topicrepository.findAll();
    }
```

TopicRepository:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import com.web.app.Emodel.Bicicleta;

public interface TopicRepository extends CrudRepository<Bicicleta, Long> {

}
```

Ficou mais fácil de entender desmembrando, para mim ficou mais fácil também de entender a classe service e a repository, criei uma interface ao invés da classe.